# Is there a way to simplify this boolean assignment?

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-expression

I have a boolean `dupe` which determines whether two month/year selections are the same... and assigns the appropriate true/false accordingly.

Sometime thereafter, once a certain action is acted upon, dependent on whether `dupe` is true or not, dupe is turned off (made false)...

I have the following:

```
dupe = (dupe)?false:dupe;
```

Which seems fine and I know that works, but I have this weird feeling that it could be made simpler... am I imagining things, or is there a better way of doing this?

I've been staring at this for the good part of ten minutes, and I would rather have an answer than go insane... so can someone please set me straight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
dupe = !dupe || false;
```

However, note that if

> dependent on whether dupe is true or not, dupe is turned off

You are setting dupe to `false` if it's `true`, and `false` if it's `false`, that means it's always going to be `false`.

So you might as well do this:

```
dupe = false;
```

Comment: Oh geez... I think you may have hit on a good point there...

"that means it's always going to be false"

So really... all I need to do is `dupe = false`

I was wondering why this wasn't making any sense... I was over-complicating it, after all... Thanks Bryce for the clarification...

Comment: Which means Deepanshu and his `dupe=false` is the shortest we can get (except dupe=0 of course)

Comment: What can change if you **OR** something with **FALSE**? It is exactly the same as `dupe=!dupe;` Besides, if you want to turn dupe off, why don' t you just assign it to **FALSE**?

Comment: @mplungjan well, I'm only setting `dupe` initially to `true` or `false`, there's no loose type 0's or 1's to meddle with it... 

But indeed `dupe = false` is simpler...

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dupe){
   dupe =false;
}else{
   dupe=dupe
}
```

so basically

you are setting **dupe=false;** whether it is false or true

so you should place `dupe= false;`

Comment: I didn't want it to toggle... I wanted it to turn false if it's true, else remain false.

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio if all you want is to set that variable to false no matter what... Why not just set it to false straight away?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio yea, i realised that and I was editing the answer